# Is it possible to put duplicate style in a .less component

Tags: css, less

Is it possible to put certain css style in a component and reuse it in different locations? In the example below, I am repeating the same style for `.navigation` class:

```
.container-1 {
    .navigation {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media (max-width:991px) {
    .container-1 {
        .navigation {
            margin-top: 0px;             // <-- repeated
            background-color: #252525;   // <-- repeated
            width: 250px;                // <-- repeated
        }
    }
}

.container-2 {
    .navigation {
        margin-top: 0px;             // <-- repeated
        background-color: #252525;   // <-- repeated
        width: 250px;                // <-- repeated
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In less you can use `Mixins` for this:

```css
.navigation-styles {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

@media (max-width:991px) {
    .container-1 {
        .navigation {
             .navigation-styles();
        }
    }
}

.container-2 {
    .navigation {
        .navigation-styles();
    }
}
```

Please take a look at the doc [here](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature)